# Java ClassCastException when generating WSDL in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, classcastexception

I am trying to create a new Web Service in Eclipse (bottom up, apache axis 1, tomcat 6), but I get warnings before the attempt and then an error after.

**Error:**

```
IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer
```

Here is where I use Serializable:

```
public class IntegrationUtils extends Utilities implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7515033201857603982L;
```

**Summary of Warnings:**
A lot of the warnings have to do with classes used by my web service class not having *default constructors*.

Here are the warnings:

```
The service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
The service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
  The field or property "headers" on the value type "org.apache.axis.AxisFault" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.util.ArrayList", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "cause" on the value type "java.rmi.RemoteException" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.lang.Throwable", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "noClasses" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "noObjects" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.lang.Object", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "propertyDescriptorMap" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.util.Map", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "type" on the value type "org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "actualType" on the value type "org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "javaType" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.FieldDesc" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "headers" on the value type "org.apache.axis.AxisFault" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.util.ArrayList", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "cause" on the value type "java.rmi.RemoteException" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" has a data type, "java.lang.Throwable", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The value type "org.w3c.dom.Element" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.apache.axis.description.FieldDesc" used via the service class "net.abc.Indy.WebService.IntegrationUtils" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: I can't help you but it may help others if you specify which version of Axis you are using?

Comment: Is there a reason for using the older version of axis?

Comment: server is out of date and the project is too big to update it just for this :(

Answer (score 0):

You get a ClassCastException, whenever you have duplicate JARs or JAR-files with the same class-files in it. In you case it could be a different Axis version too. The problem typically occures, when your tomcat instantiates a axis-class and sends this instance to your application. Your application on the other side can uses its own jars (packaged into you WAR or EAR). And because of the posibility of a multi classloader hirarchie in a Web- or Java EE-Container you can run different webapps with there own jar-files-versions at the same server at the same time.

But how to solve it? Well, search for these classes (shown in the StackTrace) in all jars of you tomcat and your web-application and check, which one is used to instantiate Axis-Requests/-responses. The easiest solution is, to remove the relevant jar from you web application and to compile your code against the jar's of you runtime environment (your tomcat). If the tomcat-jar-versions are not usable for your case, try to patch the server-jars.
An alternative solution can be a different configuration of your web-application/server to controll the classloaders.